# how to cache a dynamic page in jQuery Mobile with single page navigation?

Tags: ajax, caching, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm programming in Phonegap with jQM and I have a single page navigation using Ajax and changepage() like this:

first page: loads some data from a server to an JSON object (categories with a bunch of items each category)

second page: user select a category -> set variable in localStorage.category

third page: displaying the items dynamically base on the variable setting in localStorage.category

Now I want to cache the third page with all the possibilities to display data using loadPage() in the successCallback from getting the JSON object. I haven't found any working solutions yet...Is there a way to do this (with jQM)?

Comment: Do you have code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using something like Backbone.js and Underscore.js's templates to do this. Your spesific question(get JSON, bind to a new view) is answered in this tutorial:

http://thomasdavis.github.com/2011/02/01/backbone-introduction.html

(paragraph Setting up the main view, though I recommend reading it all)

Using backbone.js you can get the MVC arcitecture to work with your code and then the view populates itself when you bind a new model to it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the reply but Backbone.js doesn't solve my caching problem does it?

Comment: Well, then you can just prefetch the page. <a href="#catPage" data-prefetch> (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-cache.html)